# Why doesn't using a for loop this way replace each item in the list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
['G1X0.000Y3.000', 'G2X2.000Y3.000I1.000J2.291', 'G1X2.000Y-0.000', 'G2X0.000Y0.000I-1.000J-2.291']
```

The formatting is such that if the numeric content after X,Y,I or J are positive there is no + sign but if they are negative then the - sign is included. I am trying to loop through this list and to basically add the + sign if there is no - sign at the start of the numeric content. The result should look like this:

```
['G1X+0.000Y+3.000', 'G2X+2.000Y+3.000I+1.000J+2.291', 'G1X+2.000Y-0.000', 'G2X+0.000Y+0.000I-1.000J-2.291']
```

I'm trying to use a list comprehension to do so as follows:

```
#Make sure that X, Y, I and J start with + or - 
for count,i in enumerate(fileContents):
    if 'G' in i:
        indexOfI = i.index("X")
        if(i[indexOfI+1]!="-"):
            print(i[:indexOfI+1] + "+" + i[indexOfI+1:])
            fileContents[count] = i[:indexOfI+1] + "+" + i[indexOfI+1:]

        indexOfY = i.index("Y")
        if(i[indexOfY+1]!="-"):
            fileContents[count] = i[:indexOfY+1] + "+" + i[indexOfY+1:]

    if "G2" in i:
        indexOfI = i.index("I")
        if(i[indexOfI+1]!="-"):
            fileContents[count] = i[:indexOfI+1] + "+" + i[indexOfI+1:]

        indexOfJ = i.index("J")
        if(i[indexOfJ+1]!="-"):
            fileContents[count] = i[:indexOfJ+1] + "+" + i[indexOfJ+1:]
```

the statement `print(i[:indexOfI+1] + "+" + i[indexOfI+1:])` gives an output in the console of:

```
G1X+0.000Y3.000
G2X+2.000Y3.000I1.000J2.291
G1X+2.000Y-0.000
G2X+0.000Y0.000I-1.000J-2.291
```

Which shows me that this performs what I want it to, however if I print `fileContents` after this function there are no changes to the list. In other words the following line of code does not replace the list item in each position as I expect it to:

```
fileContents[count] = i[:indexOfI+1] + "+" + i[indexOfI+1:]
```

Why does this not work when I can do the following and it does update the list correctly?

```
#Format each command to a 32 byte string
for i, s in enumerate(fileContents):
    fileContents[i] =s.ljust(32,'#')
```

**edit**: I originally titled the post "Why doesn't using a list comprehension this way replace each item in the list?". Users have kindly pointed out this has nothing to do with a list comprehension. I apologise, I thought this format `x in list` was a list comprehension.

Comment: there is no list comprehension in your code

Comment: Don't know why you reference list comprehension in the title of your question because you don't appear to be using any of those. But don't worry, for loops are fine.

Comment: What is `s[indexOfI+1]`?

Comment: Why not learn about and then use regular expressions? Parsing based on `.index()` is typically on the fragile side.

Comment: @trincot small typo, have corrected to be `i[indexOfI+1]`

Comment: Your example printout doesn't have + after the Y

Comment: @barny I'm just printing out after the part which checks for X

Comment: You see the four repeated bits of code - those should be in a function that you call with the character to check, then you only have to write and maintain it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I print `fileContents` after this function there are no changes to the list.

Actually, there are changes, but at most *one* `+` is added (the last one).

This is because you don't apply the same change to `i`, which means that the next `if` blocks will copy a part from `i` back to `fileContents[count]` that didn't have the *previous* change.

The quick fix is to make sure you apply the change *also* to `i`. Something like:

```
fileContents[count] = i = i[:indexOfI+1] + "+" + i[indexOfI+1:]
#                     ^^^^
```

You can perform this task with list comprehension using `re.sub`:

```
import re
fileContents = [re.sub(r"([XYIJ])(?=\d)", r"\1+", line) for line in fileContents]
```

This will match any X, Y, I or J followed by a digit. In that case, a plus is inserted between those. If you need more strict matching rules, where the line must start with "G", ...etc, then the regular expression will become more complex.

Comment: Thanks for this quick fix! Out of interest is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Added a solution with list comprehension to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
for i, s in enumerate(fileContents):
```

you iterate over the `fileContents` list, which you want to change in the same loop. It's always dangerous.

Iterate over a *copy* of this list, which you may simply create by adding [:] to it:

```
for i, s in enumerate(fileContents[:]):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `+` after any of these chars, then replace back `+-` (f any) with `-`:

```
def my_replace(item):
    for char in 'XYIJ':
        item = item.replace(char, f'{char}+')
    return item.replace('+-', '-')

spam = ['G1X0.000Y3.000', 'G2X2.000Y3.000I1.000J2.291',
        'G1X2.000Y-0.000', 'G2X0.000Y0.000I-1.000J-2.291']
eggs = [my_replace(item) for item in spam] # now, this is list comprehension
print(eggs)
```

output

```
['G1X+0.000Y+3.000', 'G2X+2.000Y+3.000I+1.000J+2.291', 'G1X+2.000Y-0.000', 'G2X+0.000Y+0.000I-1.000J-2.291']
```